# UICollectionview within a custom UIView which is a subview in another view always appears nil

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, xib

I have a Custom View(MainView) which has another Custom View(SecondView). The SecondView has a UICollectionView inside it. The MainView is loaded inside the View controller here is a snippet for it

```
  private weak var eventDetailsView: EBEventDetailsView? {
    if isViewLoaded {
      return view as? EBEventDetailsView
    }
    return nil
  }

  override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    if let eventDetailsView = EBEventDetailsView.loadFromNib(nibName: "EBEventDetailsView") {
      view = eventDetailsView
    }
  }
```

I have a protocol which loads the view perfectly. The protocol is as follows:

```
protocol UIViewLoading {}
extension UIView : UIViewLoading {}
extension UIViewLoading where Self : UIView {
  static func loadFromNib(nibName: String) -> Self? {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
    return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? Self
  }
}
```

Here is what the EBEventDetailsView looks like:

```
class EBEventDetailsView: EventBuzzBaseView {

  @IBOutlet weak var detailSegment: UISegmentedControl!

  @IBOutlet weak var detailView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var messagesView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var photosView: EBPhotosView!
}
```

The problem here is when i load the above view. The EBPhotosView which has a UICollectionView which is always nil
Here is EBPhotosView:

```
class EBPhotosView: EventBuzzBaseView {

  @IBOutlet weak var photosCollectionView: UICollectionView!

}
```

Can someone help me with this what I'm doing wrong? I have tried adding a common init in the EBEventDetailsView which loads the nib for the first time but as soon as I hide the view i find nil again?

Comment: Try removing the term `weak`.

Comment: removed from weak for both the photosView as well as photosCollectionView still crashing

Comment: I'm afraid I don't grasp what you are trying to do, sorry. Can you reproduce the problem as a minimal project and post it? You say the EBPhotosView "has a UICollectionView which is always `nil`" but nothing is present in the code you've shown that would ever make it be _not_ `nil` so it's hard to see what the surprise is. And you have not shown what you are doing when you crash with the `nil` unwrapping, so it's not even clear how you know there's a problem.

Comment: Also I don't understand what you think the protocol is for. To inject a method into UIView, just extend UIView; no protocol is needed for that.

Comment: i will try and post a minimal project

Comment: here is the link to the repo https://github.com/rameeznkhan/EventsBug

Comment: Isn't the problem that your EBEventDetailsView xib itself contains an empty EBPhotosView? That EBPhotosView is empty, it contains no collection view, its PhotosCollectionView is nil.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166217/discussion-between-rameez-and-matt).